# Qt resources .js files can not load in release mode

Tags: javascript, qt

I want to load an external JavaScript file index.js in index.html within QWebEngineView.

qrc file:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>index.html</file>
    <file>index.js</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

index.js and index.html file:

```js
console.log('test');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use `ui->widget->load(QUrl("qrc:/index.html"));` to load the html file, and run in debug mode. It works fine, I can see "Hello world!" and console message "test". When I run in release mode, I got a `Resource :/index.js not found or is empty`.

I can see some difference files in release build folder, like `index_js.cpp` which not generated in debug mode, it seems that qml engine load the js file. How to disable it and load js file in release mode properly?

My Qt Version: 5.12.7 MSVC2017 64bit.

Comment: I never played with that but are you sure you can use QRC resources and load them with the classic HTML syntax? ` <script src="index.js"></script>` -- to me this HTML tag will only look for a local URL. Why do you think QML engine loads the js file, as you don't seem to use QML to display the webview?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (Qt Version: 5.12.9 MSVC2017 32bit), but I found a solution (crutch).

I think it's a Qt bug. Only files with the *.js extension do not get into the resources, then I just renamed them.
For example: `index.js` rename to `index.j`

And then in the html-file:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

change to:

```
<script src="index.j"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, the right one solution. It seems that quick compiler process js file.
But i  also loaded qwechannel.js - nothing wrong with this file. Other js files are empty.
If i use only widgets projects - i`ve got no problem with js loading.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a javascript for loading GoogleMaps in a qrc resource file. The file contained code like this:

```
async function initMap()
{
 const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
.
.
.
```

The clang always displayed the async line with a red warning "expected token ',' but loading the file never failed. However, when I tried to compile the program in Release mode, the compile failed on that line. Disabling the QtQuick Compiler allowed the app to compile.